# How do I view the full contents of a workspace variable in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, variables, workspace

I am having a problem viewing a workspace variable in its entirety in Matlab. Specifically, I have a cell array that has dimensions 1x81. Matlab will only show the first 16 elements of this cell array and I would like to be able to view all of them when I click on the variable in the workspace section.

I have tried looking for a setting that controls how variables are shown in the workspace but haven't had any luck finding a solution to this specific problem.

Thanks for any help.

Additional Info:
To reproduce my issue all I had to do was run the following and view the variable myCell by clicking on it in the variable workspace.

```
for i = 1:81
    myCell{i} = 1;
end
```

Here is a screenshot of what my workspace variable looks like, if you look at the scroll bar at the bottom you can see that it doesn't move any further to the right to show more of the cell array elements.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. There are scroll bars at the side and bottom of the variable viewer...

Comment: I've only had the issue with Matlab R2016a, never with previous versions. I have the scroll bars but it only allows me to move over a limited number of the cell entries, in my case 16 out of the 81. It doesn't just happen on one particular cell array either, it's almost all of them that are longer than about 20 cells.

Comment: Unless you can provide a means to reproduce your issue I would suggest you contact Technical Support.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in 2016a.

You can follow the [link](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1350885) and the instructions to correct that bug.